# Lightweight word tokenizer that also stores the position/index of each word like spacy (token.i)

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy

I need to store the index of all words in my sentences.

**Please recommend something other than spacy** (which has similar word tokenization accuracy) as Spacy "doc" object is slowing down my further **operations** (mentioned at the end)

I am currently using spacy to do it as it has a very simple way to do this out of the box (token.index).

**Example code below:**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "I eat mangoes and I eat oranges"
spacy_doc = nlp(text)
print("spacy_doc: ", spacy_doc,'\n')
for token in spacy_doc:
    #token.i gets the index (spacy's functionality..)
    print(token,"-->",token.i)
```

**Output:**

```
spacy_doc:  I eat mangoes and I eat oranges 

    I --> 0
    eat --> 1
    mangoes --> 2
    and --> 3
    I --> 4
    eat --> 5
    oranges --> 6
```

As you can see this is extremely easy to use and very robust as it even takes duplicate words into account (for example eat has been shown to have 2 indexes).

**What I have already tried:**

- Use [token2index](https://github.com/Kaleidophon/token2index) , but it's not robust as it does not account for
  duplicate words as in the above example and it also does not have a
  simple attribute like spacy (token2index simply creates a dictionary
  of token vs index)
- I have also tried loading spacy models without any components (code below) but it
  did not help speeding up my operations (referenced in the
  end).. May be someone can recommend how to just load spacy models
  with just  tokenizers that helps speeding up my operations.

**loading spacy models without components**

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',exclude = ['tok2vec','tagger','parser','senter','attribute_ruler','lemmatizer','ner'])
```

**operations**  = In a window of 5 tokens, Get every combination of 3 tokens appearing one after the other but not necessarily are consecutive  then use this list later to get index of each token.

**Code**

```
def possible_long_forms(spacy_doc_object):    

    window_list_3 = []
    for i in range(len(spacy_doc_object)):
        if (i <= (len(spacy_doc_object) - 5)) or (i==0):
            window_list_3.append(spacy_doc_object[i:i+5])
    
    window_list_3 = list(map(lambda x:list(itertools.combinations(x,3)) , window_list_3))

    return window_list_3

spacy_doc_new = nlp("I like mobiles and laptops")
results = possible_long_forms(spacy_doc_new)
print(results,'\n')
first_word_of_first_tuple_in_results = results[0][0][0]
print("Check index", ":", first_word_of_first_tuple_in_results,"-->",first_word_of_first_tuple_in_results.i)
```

#Output

```
[[(I, like, mobiles),
  (I, like, and),
  (I, like, laptops),
  (I, mobiles, and),
  (I, mobiles, laptops),
  (I, and, laptops),
  (like, mobiles, and),
  (like, mobiles, laptops),
  (like, and, laptops),
  (mobiles, and, laptops)]]
  
  Check index : I --> 0
```

As you can understand this requires iterating through the whole sentence. I could have simply done sentence.split() and converted the sentence but one should note that the position of each token is lost in such task..

Comment: Can you share how you do the operations part? Maybe you could use spaCy once for preprocessing, store the information you need in a suitable format, and use that as input for your main task?

Comment: If you reduce the `Doc` object to something like `index_toks = [(token.i, token.text) for token in spacy_doc_new]` and then do `possible_long_forms(index_toks)`, would it be fast enough?

Comment: @fsimonjetz ,Replying to your 1st comment , I have added the code as well now :)

Comment: Saw that, my second comment is referring to that ;) I noticed another thing, you compute `len(spacy_doc_object)` over and over again - that's costly. Better store it in a variable before the loop and use the variable.

Comment: @fsimonjetz , Replying to your 2nd comment , the problem with this approach is that I am losing the index information as a characteristic of the token as we are storing the index in a tuple.. It will create problems when 2 duplicate words are mentioned in the text. Ideally I want to continue to use token.i to get index of token. Hope that request makes sense :)

Comment: The idea is to create combinations of tuples so you'd get `[[(('I', 0), ('like', 1), ('mobiles', 2), ...], ...]`. So you'd always have a token string and its index and duplicates would still be recognizable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @fsimonjetz Thanks for the patience mate. So I have implemented your suggestion for storing length in a variable --> unfortunately it did not speed the process much. It only went from 47 to 46 seconds......... Regarding the tuples , the problem is at later stages in the code , I have to use the position of the token. Let's say I have the word "eat" from "I eat mangoes and I eat oranges", how do I know if it's the eat at 2nd index or eat at 6th index ?..... I am creating a module to find full forms for acronyms , but I think mentioning more code will consume more of your time.

Comment: You'd know because the index is always in the tuple alongside its corresponding token string - one would be `("eat", 1)` and the other `("eat", 5)`.